# what is wrong in this find average and total?

Tags: php, average

yeah I am a noob...I am trying to learn php on my own and this is too hard. AH

```
<?php
$score=array(80,90,90,99,78);

    $total=0;
    $for ($a=0; $a<=5; $a++) {
            $total=$score+1;
    }
    $avg = $total/5;
    echo ("score $score[0], $score [1], $score [2], $score [3], $score [4] <br>";
    echo ("total $total, average $avg <br>");
?>
```

Comment: You tell us "what is wrong"

Comment: sidenote: you really dont need parenthesis on those echos

Comment: @sectus isn't this website about asking questions? why are you so negative? If you aren't going to help why even bother to comment?

Comment: All these people just copying the code and not testing. Didn't notice OP has **`$for`** instead of `for`.....

Comment: Just be more specific when you have trouble. "this is my code and it's wrong" -- is not a good question. Print all error messages, show expected and output values. Show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$score being an array can't be added as an integer.

Try:
$total+=$score[$a]

Also it should be < 5, not <= 5, or better yet use count($score) in case you want to ever add or remove from the array:

```
$total=0;
for ($a=0; $a<count($score); $a++) {
        $total+=$score[$a];
}
$avg = $total/count($score);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to inside for loop statement

```
$total=$score+1;
```

to

```
$total+=$score[$a];
```

**Update:** Many errors try this code

```
<?php
$score=array(80,90,90,99,78);

    $total=0;
    for ($a=0; $a< count($score); $a++) {
           $total+=$score[$a];
    }
    $avg = $total/count($score);
    echo ("score $score[0], $score[1], $score[2], $score[3], $score[4] <br>");
    echo ("total $total, average $avg <br>");
?>
```

- [**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/GKnCsaKJ)

Answer (score 0):

You have more syntax errors like `$for` and `echo statement` in your code. you need to add all values to your `$total`

```
 $score=array(80,90,90,99,78);
 $total=0;
 for ($a=0; $a<=count($score); $a++) {
    $total = $total+$score[$a]; //$total+=$score[$a];
 }
 $avg = $total/5;
 echo "score". $score[0]. $score [1]. $score [2].$score [3]. $score[4] ."<br>";
 echo "total $total, average $avg <br>";
```

or use short code:- using [array_sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and `count()`

```
  $score = array(80,90,90,99,78);
  echo $total = array_sum($score);
  echo $avg = $total/count($score);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at your loop, you're **replacing** $total with a new value everytime. You're not summing the scores. You therefore have to use `$total = $total + something;`

Next is, since $score is an array, you should use `$score[index]` (in this case, the index is $a) instead of `$score` to refer to the elements inside the array.

This would be the result :

```
$total=0;
$for ($a=0; $a<=5; $a++) {
    $total=$total+$score[$a]+1;
}
$avg = $total/5;
```